# Auto Sync on filesave Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: dreamweaver, synchronize, remote-server

I've set up the remote server so clicking on the file will download it to my local folder. After I made some changes I have to click on synchronize with server etc.

Is there a way to synchronize with server when I simply save the file?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? If your remote server contains the live site, you do not want your work-in-progress development copy of the site that you're working on to be uploaded to the server every time you save the file for testing/debugging.

Comment: Yes, It's a closed site and I'm doing it simply because dreamweaver can't figure out to show the site in live view correctly. I remember you can do it in CS4, can't see such option here...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This really isn't a good idea as mentioned above, but yes, you can do this.

Open up the site definition: `Site -> Manage Sites` select your site, then click `Edit`. Select the `Servers` category, select your remote server and click `Edit`            (pencil) or double click the server name. Switch to the `Advanced` tab and check `Automatically upload files to server on save`